# How to extend a function

Tags: c++, function, oop

is there a way in modern C++ to "extend" a function?
Maybe this pseudo code can explain what I want:

```
extendable void foo()
{
   doSomething();
}

extend foo()
{
   moo();
}
```

when compiled the function `foo()` should do this:

```
foo()
{
    doSomething();
    moo();
}
```

I thought I could do this by storing every function that I want to have in `foo()` in a std::vector of function pointers and `foo()` will loop through the vector and run all functions.

However, I need to do this while compiling, thus I can't run `vector.push_back()`.

I tried to do this with help of #define directives but I didn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

### EDIT: My actual problem

I want to implement some kind of Entity-Component-System with a list for every component. Every entity has an ID that points to the list element in the component-list.
Because I don't want to repeat the steps for creating a new type of component I wanted to make a #define-directive to make this automatically for every new component I'll create.

The main problem is to add to every component-vector one element if a new entity is created.
This is the code I wanted to work:

```
#define addComponent(name)                                          \
    struct name;                                                    \
private:                                                            \
    std::vector<name> name ## vector;                               \
public:                                                             \
    extend addEntity()                                              \
    {                                                               \
        struct name a;                                              \
        name ## vector.push_back(a);                                \
    }                                                               \
    void set ## name(const int & ID, name newName)                  \
    {                                                               \
        name ## vector[ID] = newName;                               \
    }                                                               \
    name get ## name(const int & ID)                                \
    {                                                               \
        return name ## vector[ID];                                  \
    }

class Component
{
public:
    Component();
    ~Component();

    extendable void addEntity(int * ID);

    addComponent(position)
    struct position
    {
        float x, y, z;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is called a "virtual method". And it's not "modern", but this existed since the dawn of C++.

Comment: Let's go back a step - WHY do you need this?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb: Please **edit your question** to motivate it much more and explain *why* you want to do such things and for what kind of programs.

Comment: Your macro obviously don't and can't work. So how did you consider solving your problem (which I still find very unclear, even after editing)?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I extend functions?

No.

What you describe is not possible. Having the compiler generate a function that will call the function that `foo()` invoked before being extended is not supported by any mechanism.

Virtual methods do not do the trick, since all they provide is [Polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) (many forms in Greek).

Comment: I can't see how virtual methods are in any way comparable to what the question is describing.

Comment: But virtual functions need to be member functions, that is methods applied to objects. Read also about [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: You can't extend functions with `virtual` though. You can possibly override them, that's all.

Comment: Depending on the context virtual functions MAY solve his problem - but then we don't really know what his problem is yet. Let's hope he clarifies.

Answer (score 3):

You don't explain enough what you have in mind and why (even *after* your edit). For member functions, indeed read more about [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) (a common way to implement [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)).

Notice however that functions can be values (thanks to [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) notably).

You might then declare for example a double ended queue `todoque` of functions using [std::dequeue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) (it could be a `static` variable or a field of some `class`, etc...)

```
 std::deque<std::function<void(void)>> todoque;
```

and extend it, perhaps  using a lambda,

```
 todoque.push_back([](void) { moo(); };
```

and initialize it with

```
  todoque{[](void){doSomething()}};
```

then code

```
 void foo() {
   for (auto f : todoque) f();
 }
```

I hope you got the idea.

BTW, in the example above the lambda are perhaps unneeded, you might just code `todoque.push_back(moo)`.

BTW I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (not about C++, but about a functional programming language called Scheme), it is an excellent (and freely downloadable) introduction to programming.

> I thought I could do this by storing every function that I want to have in foo() in a std::vector of function pointers

No, or even better, make it a `std::vector<std::function<void(void)>>`  and use lambda expressions.

> However, I need to do this while compiling, thus I can't run vector.push_back()

Why not? It might happen in a constructor of some static data.

Maybe your overall goal (which you don't explain) might be also achieved by run-time metaprogramming techniques involving [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) and generation of code at runtime. You could use libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/); you could also emit C++ code in some temporary file, compile it as a plugin, and [dlopen](https://helpmanual.io/man3/dlopen-posix/) that plugin. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257270/40065).

Regarding your edited Entity-Component-System goal, did you consider writing some specialized C++ code generator (or preprocessor) that appropriate rules of your build automation system (e.g. `make`  or `ninja`, etc...) would trigger wisely at build time? The Qt [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) could be inspirational. Consider also using some general purpose preprocessor like `m4` or [gpp](https://logological.org/gpp).

Comment: It is probably a specialized code generator what I need if I am not able to find a solution with preprocessor directives.