# Can someone explain the differences between lambda in C++11 and inline function?

Tags: c++11

As stated in the title, what are the differences between C++11 lambda and the tradition inline function?

Answer (score 1):

A [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) evaluates to some [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), and is a first-class value (an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)) which you could store in some [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) variable. Read more about [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and about [bound and free variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables) and about [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

A closure mixes code and data -closed values- and represents a mathematical function (computed when that closure is [applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_application)).

For example [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) are often used with lambda expressions. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025660/841108).

An optimizing compiler might *sometimes* optimize a closure application as an [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) function call.

Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) to understand why functional values are so important.